# Change Android kernel version name before compiling

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, android-7.1-nougat

I've successfully managed to build the **ElementalX** kernel for my Android phone running the latest firmware **Nougat 7.1.1**, however after flashing the kernel on my device and heading to **Settings>About phone** and checking the **Kernel version** i see that the kernel is given a peculiar string name. How do i modify the string name to my own needs before compiling the kernel a second time?

Is there a specific file i should be targeting?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684811/how-to-change-version-string-of-the-kernel.

Comment: @vinod maverick ok thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change version string of the kernel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684811/how-to-change-version-string-of-the-kernel)